# How to reset password for Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, comexception

Does anyone know how can I reset password for Active Directory in C#?

I wrote the following code to reset the password in Active Directory:

> ```
>    [WebMethod]
>    public static string ResetPassword(string test)
>    {
>        string userDn = "CN=Joe Bloggs,OU=Test Accounts,OU=ST IT,OU=Departments,OU=Internal,OU=Divisions,DC=thegroup,DC=com,DC=au";
>        string password = "!qwer12345";
>
>        DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
>        uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
>        uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
>
>        uEntry.Close();
>
>        return "hello";
>    }
> ```

When I run the code, an error displays when it reaches the line `uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });`

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this issue and how I could fix it?

Comment: Well, did you check the `ErrorCode` property of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.adsi.narkive.com/iaZ64bk1/comexception-0x80004005-unspecified-error-when-creating-a-user-in-ad-via-web-service) seems to explain the cause of the issue- you need to supply admin credentials (username and password).

> I would think it's a security issue - when you're running it locally
>   on Windows directly, it's being executed under your own account, which
>   most likely has enough privileges to create the user.
>
> When you do it through the web service, you run it as the "anonymous"
>   ASP.NET user which by default most likely won't have the permissions
>   to do this.
>
> So when you bind to AD, you will need to supply credentials (username
>   and password) that are sufficiently priviledged to be able to create
>   users. You can do this in the "new DirectoryEntry()" constructor -
>   check it's overloads.